# Python SQLite insert data from variables

Tags: python, json, sqlite

I am trying to add the contents of variables into a SQLite DB but I am getting an error of

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

My code is:-

```
import requests
import json
import eventlet
import os
import sqlite3

#Get the currect vuln_sets
response = requests.get('https://vulners.com/api/v3/search/stats/')
vuln_set = json.loads(response.text)
vuln_type = vuln_set['data']['type_results']
for k in vuln_type:
    vuln_bulletinfamily = vuln_set['data']['type_results'][k]['bulletinFamily']
    vuln_name = vuln_set['data']['type_results'][k]['displayName']
    vuln_count = vuln_set['data']['type_results'][k]['count']



con = sqlite3.connect('vuln_sets.db')
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row


    cur.execute("REPLACE INTO vuln_sets (vulntype, displayname, bulletinfamily, count) values (?, ?, ?, ?)", (vuln_type, vuln_bulletinfamily, vuln_name, vuln_count))
    con.commit()
```

The variables contain the JSON key pairs as I need to insert some of them into the DB for processing but a different project.

The stacktrace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 24, in <module>
    cur.execute("REPLACE INTO vuln_sets (vulntype, displayname, bulletinfamily, count) values (?, ?, ?, ?);", (vuln_type, vuln_bulletinfamily, vuln_name, vuln_count))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Comment: can you give a full stacktrace ?

Comment: `vuln_type` is a list. I can see this because you're iterating through it earlier in the code. You cannot insert a list. I think you want all of the code indented to be inside the `for k in vuln_type:` loop and replace `vuln_type` with `k` in your query.

Comment: Added the stacktrace above

Comment: please give the table schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@roganjosh's comment fixed it! I needed to incude the DB transactions in the for loop as below:

```
import requests
import json
import eventlet
import os
import sqlite3

#Get the currect vuln_sets
response = requests.get('https://vulners.com/api/v3/search/stats/')
vuln_set = json.loads(response.text)
vuln_type = vuln_set['data']['type_results']
for k in vuln_type:
    vuln_bulletinfamily = vuln_set['data']['type_results'][k]['bulletinFamily']
    vuln_name = vuln_set['data']['type_results'][k]['displayName']
    vuln_count = vuln_set['data']['type_results'][k]['count']
    con = sqlite3.connect('vuln_sets.db')
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row    
        cur.execute("REPLACE INTO vuln_sets (vulntype, displayname, bulletinfamily, count) values (?, ?, ?, ?)", (k, vuln_name, vuln_bulletinfamily, vuln_count))
        con.commit()
```